# Best Way to Parse a Text File for DATABASE

Tags: sql, database, parsing, sorting

i have a text file in the format

```
catid: xxxxx,
description: xxxxx,
category: xxxxxx,
platform: xxxxx,
stuff-i-don't-need: xxxxxx

catid: xxxxx,
description: xxxxx,
category: xxxxxx,
platform: xxxxx,
stuff-i-don't-need: xxxxxx


catid: xxxxx,<p>
description: xxxxx,<p>
category: xxxxxx,<p>
platform: xxxxx,<p>
stuff-i-don't-need: xxxxxx<p>
```

and i need the file formatted, in the EASIEST and most effecient way possible, to a format that resembles a database CSV.

so it looks like

```
cat id      description         category             platform
xxxxx       xxxxxxxx           xxxxxxxx              xxxxxxxx
xxxxx       xxxxxxxx           xxxxxxxx              xxxxxxxx
xxxxx       xxxxxxxx           xxxxxxxx              xxxxxxxx
```

stuff-i-don't-need is ... well, stuff i don't need.

i would like to know how to do this.... using software like SQL DATABASE importer,
or at least PHP.

thanks in advance.

edit* i need to know what the best software/language would be to use to parse text files to get the results described above. thanks

Comment: Read the file, parse it, create a new one in desired format.

Comment: This is a broad question. Where exactly are you stuck on this?

Comment: i've used Excel, PHP, and SQL data base importer. i just can't seem to get the vertical listing into categorized HORIZONTAL listings. no matter what i did, it didn't work. it's a simple question, the answer is right in front of me, but i think i'm having a dumb-out moment. any suggstions how to do this?

Comment: It's not a simple question. There is the issue of where your data is coming from, at one point in the process are you looking to change the format, are you looking to use a tool to set up CSV data or wanting to write code, and what is your output, etc., etc.? I do not think you've been sufficiently clear on everything that you are trying to do. Also, you've shown absolutely no effort of your own or details about a specific thing that you are stuck on. Sorry, for that reason, this question is not appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: It seems all you are looking for is how to convert your text file from one format into another. I see no dbms involved here. You could achieve the conversion with some search and replace commands in an editor or you could write a small program to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your original file format, it looks more or less an array of JSON objects

With some simple tweeks, you can convert the file to a typical JSON array as follows:

```
[
  {
    catid: "xxxxx",
    description: "xxxxx",
    category: "xxxxxx",
    platform: "xxxxx",
    stuff-i-dont-need: "xxxxxx"
  },
  {
   catid: "xxxxx",
   description: "xxxxx",
   category: "xxxxxx",
   platform: "xxxxx",
   stuff-i-dont-need: "xxxxxx"
  }
]
```

Changes I did are as follows:

1. contained values in double quotes
2. removed special character from headers (i.e. changed "don't" to "dont")
3. contained each record in curly braces, which can be easily done using any editor by find and replace

Then you can use many online tools to automatically parse your JSON array into CSV

I tried [this one](https://json-csv.com/) and it worked perfectly